# My program is only printing "ddddddddd" instead of the map?

Tags: c

My code is on paste bin and will permanently be there. The problem with my program is that when I try to load it up it just prints `dddddddddddd` can you please. Try to help me fix it. This is should print out all the lines to form the map.

```
int main() {

    TEST_LEVEL();    
    LOAD_LEVEL();

    return 0;

}


char  inttorow(int number);

//global
char * R1[81] ;
char * R2[81] ;
char * R3[81] ;
char * R4[81] ;
char * R5[81] ;
char * R6[81] ;
char * R7[81] ;
char * R8[81] ;
char * R9[81] ;
char * R10[81] ;
char * R11[81] ;
char * R12[81] ;
char * R13[81] ;
char * R14[81] ;
char * R15[81] ;
char * R16[81] ;
char * R17[81] ;
char * R18[81] ;
char * R19[81] ;
char * R20[81] ;
char * R21[81] ;
char * R22[81] ;
char * R23[81] ;
char * R24[81] ;
char * R25[81] ;
int character;
int spawn[2];
int door1[2];
int door2[2];
int door3[2];
int door4[2];


//maps
void TEST_LEVEL(){    

 *R1="################################################################################";
 *R2="#                                                                              #";
 *R3="#                                                                              #";
 *R4="#                                                                              #";
 *R5="#                                                                              #";
 *R6="#                                                                              #";
 *R7="#                                                                              #";
 *R8="#                                                                              #";
 *R9="#                                                                               #";
*R10="                                                                               #";
*R11="#                                                                               #";
*R12="#                                                                              #";
*R13="#                                                                              #";
*R14="#                                                                              #";
*R15="#                                                                              #";
*R16="#                                                                              #";
*R17="#                                                                              #";
*R18="#                                                                              #";
*R19="#                                                                              #";
*R20="#                                                                              #";
*R21="#                                                                              #";
*R22="#                                                                              #";
*R23="#                                                                              #";
*R24="#                                                                              #";
*R25="################################################################################";

 spawn[1] = 15;
 spawn[2] = 15;


return;


  }


//movement


//tools
void LOAD_LEVEL(){
  char * row[81];
  int i = 1;
while(i != 25){
  *row =  inttorow(i);
   printf("%s\n", row);
    i++;

}


return;

}


char  inttorow(int number){
   char * row[81];

    switch(number){

     case 1 :
        *row = R1;
        break;

        case 2 :
        *row = R2;
        break;
        case 3 :
        *row = R3;
        break;
        case 4 :
        *row = R4;
        break;
        case 5 :
        *row = R5;
        break;
        case 6 :
        *row = R6;
        break;
        case 7 :
        *row = R7;
        break;
        case 8 :
        *row = R8;
        break;
        case 9 :
        *row = R9;
        break;
        case 10 :
        *row = R10;
        break;
        case 11 :
        *row = R11;
        break;
        case 12 :
        *row = R12;
        break;
        case 13 :
        *row = R13;
        break;
        case 14 :
        *row = R14;
        break;
        case 15 :
        *row = R15;
        break;
        case 16 :
        *row = R16;
        break;
        case 17 :
        *row = R17;
        break;
        case 18 :
        *row = R18;
        break;
        case 19 :
        *row = R19;
        break;
        case 20 :
        *row = R20;
        break;
        case 21 :
        *row = R21;
        break;
       case 22 :
        *row = R22;
        break;
        case 23 :
        *row = R23;
        break;
        case 24 :
        *row = R24;
        break;
        case 25 :
        *row = R25;
        break;

    }

return row;
}
```

Comment: This is a mess.  This shouldn't even compile.  I think you need to take a step back and read up on pointers, arrays, and strings.

Comment: @OldProgrammer: Surprisingly, it does compile with gcc's default settings (because gcc by default is distressingly lax). I get 32 warnings. user3600107: Did your compiler print warnings when you compiled that code? If so, fix those before worrying about how the program behaves; a stricter compiler would reject it. And defining global variables `R1`, `R2`, ..., `R25` is frankly insane; you want an array -- of what, I'm not sure.

Comment: MSVC did not compile it because of the lack of prototypes `void TEST_LEVEL();` and `void LOAD_LEVEL();`. However the function `char inttorow(int number)` is trying to return `char **` not `char` as well as the return value being a local variable. I hope you have your compiler warnings enabled.

Comment: You can flag the question to reopen if you want, btw i think you looking for this: http://ideone.com/Hxvl9E

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either the problem is in the switch case part or it is the wastage of variables after the function call ends. try making them into smaller arrays and use more for looping. To print, use %c by use of indexing.

Answer (score 0):

You have broken

```
int spawn[2];
```

by indexing thus:

```
spawn[1] = 15;
spawn[2] = 15;
```

Also the function `char inttorow(int number)` is trying to return `char **` not `char` as well as the return value being a local variable.

```
char inttorow(int number){
    char * row[81];
    ...
    return row;
}
```

I hope you have your compiler warnings enabled.

Comment: How did you wrote the answer after it was closed?

Comment: @Rizier123 perhaps because I started the answer several minutes before revising my copy and posting it.

Comment: lol for me the button was toggled i couldn't  press it